# how to display image in devexpress listbox

Tags: c#, devexpress

i need show binary image from database and display in devexpress listbox
any one can help how to solve this problem

I cannot find how to display binary image  in devexpress listbox

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to show it in list box??I think you can use [Image List box](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q235897) .

```
    Private Sub XtraForm1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim listBox As ImageListBoxControl = New ImageListBoxControl()
        listBox.ImageList = imageList1
        listBox.Items.Add("test", 0)
        listBox.Items.Add("test1", 1)

        Controls.Add(listBox)
    End Sub
```